# how to combine javascript variable to css

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

i want to make simple app with cordova jquery, i want to generate width of div based on width of screen oh phone/tablet.
i got the width of screen using this

```
var physicalScreenWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var physicalScreenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

the problem is how to combine the width of screen with my css.

this is my STATIC css, i dont know how to combine variable width to this css.
I create width:300px,130px,etc.... manually. the problem will occour when the phone/tablet with different inch..

```
.some {
margin-left:-10px;
    width:300px;
    height:130px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#aaa;
    border-right-color:#aaa;
    border-top-color:#ddd;
    border-left-color:#ddd;

}

.one{
  float:left;
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
}
.three{
    width:170px;
  height:130px;
    position:absolute;
    left:140px;

}

.four{
  width:170px;
  height:70px;
}
.five{
  width:170px;
  height:60px;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="some">
    <div class="one"><img class="bgr" src="1.jpg"></div>

    <div class="three">
        <div class="four"><p style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:2px;"><font face="arial" size="3"><b>Descc ...</b></font></p></div>
        <div class="five"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result

[image]

Comment: can't you just use % instead of px?

Comment: i knew this, % is a solution, but the problem is image in div ONE. i want to put image width and height full to div one(width and height of image = width and height of div one) any solutions ?

Comment: You don't need to give that div a specific width or height. http://jsbin.com/yajepih/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass width values to css. Instead css itself can measure the screen it is being applied to. `Media queries` is the answer for you. `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)` is for tablet and `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)` for phone.

Comment: How do you know that tablet is going to be 768px-1024px wide?

Comment: You can write css for specific sizes though. But this range applies to  normal sizes of tablets available in the market. Screens smaller than 768px can accommodate css written for phones and larger than 1024px can accommodate css written for large tablets/desktops.

Comment: Ok..then how can one handle this scenario with minimum code and maximum coverage of screen sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use simple jQuery just use:

```
$(".some").width(youtWidth);
```

EDIT:
In the same way you can set up width for each element you need. Take a look at follwing code, width of `.some` and `.one` element is set to 33% of view width.

```
var viewWidth = $(window).width();
$(".some").width(viewWidth * 0,33);
$(".one").width(viewWidth * 0,33);
```

Comment: not only in .some, but div one,three four and five i want to dynamic size based on screen of smart phone. example : width of div one = 30% from width of phone screen

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$(function(){
   var physicalScreenWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
   var physicalScreenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
   $('.some').css({width:physicalScreenWidth });
})
```

Css

```
.some{
   display:flex;
}
.one{
  flex:1;
}
.three{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
 }
```

OR you can use media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
   // write some css here
}
```

or Use css frameworks like `Bootstrap`, `Semantic`, `Bulma`

Comment: I'd definitely go with css only solution, unless there is some fundamental reason why OP should use javascript. Also he should avoid using frameworks for something this trivial.